# the birthday paradox for $p=0.5$

Tags: probability, birthday

> What is the minimum number of people such that the probability for some of them to have a common birthday is $\frac{1}{2}$?

So looking at the problem as "balls and bins". We have $n = 365$ bins and $m$ balls (people).

There's a probability of $1/n$ for two balls to be on the same bin.

Hence, the **expected number of couples** to be on the same bin is $\frac{m(m-1)}{2n}$

How can I leverage this information to conclude that the desired $m$ is $23$?

Comment: More than two people can have a birthday on the same day.

Comment: Joriki has given a nice approximation, now you can look for the smallest value of $m$ such that $\dfrac{365\times364\times\cdots(365-m+1)}{365^m}<\dfrac12$. Find why.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't conclude any exact result from this, since the expected number includes contributions from cases with more than one collision. However, when the probability of at least one collision is $\frac12$, the probability of more than one collision is still rather low, so you can get an estimate by taking the expected number as an approximation of the probability of at least one collision. Then

$$
\frac{m(m-1)}{2n}\ge\frac12
$$

yields

$$
m^2-m-n\ge0
$$

and thus

$$
m\ge\frac12+\sqrt{n+\frac14}\;,
$$

which for $n=365$ yields $m\ge20$, not a bad estimate.

Comment: Thank you joriki!